# How to start inputting values on the next row after a submit

Tags: reactjs

I would like for it to automatically start putting the values from the key down to the new row after the enter key is pressed, right now the values do display on the first row, but after the enter key is pressed it just focuses the next row and does not display the value

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"

function LetterContainer({ textColor, bgColor }) {
    const [key, setKey] = useState("")
    const [guess, setGuess] = useState([])
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
    const searchInput1 = useRef(null)
    const searchInput2 = useRef(null)
    const displayLetter = guess < 5 ? key : guess
    let userGuess = []
    
    
    useEffect(() => {    
        // Sets focus on first row for inital load
        searchInput1.current.focus()
        // Handles key up events on whole document
        function keyUp(e) {
            if (e.keyCode >= 65 && e.keyCode <= 90) {
                setKey(previous => `${previous}${e.key}`.toUpperCase().slice(0, 5))
            } else if (e.keyCode === 8) {
                setKey(previous => previous.slice(0, previous.length - 1))
            } else if (e.keyCode === 13 && key.length === 5) {
                setKey("")
                setGuess(key)
                setCounter(counter => counter + 1)
                searchInput2.current.focus()
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener("keyup", keyUp)
        return () => window.removeEventListener("keyup", keyUp)
    }, [key]);

    // Stores separated guess into array
    if (guess.length === 5) {
        userGuess = guess.split("")    
    }
    
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <div className="row">
                <input ref={searchInput1} className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} value={displayLetter.slice(0, 1)} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} value={displayLetter.slice(1, 2)} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} value={displayLetter.slice(2, 3)} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} value={displayLetter.slice(3, 4)} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} value={displayLetter.slice(4, 5)} readOnly={true} />
                <button type="submit" hidden={true}></button>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <input ref={searchInput2} className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} readOnly={true} />
                <input className="letter-tile" style={{ color: textColor, backgroundColor: bgColor }} readOnly={true} />
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't see a value in the second row since there is no `value` property set for any of the `<input>` elements. So whatever values you would like to see in the second row should be included there.

---

If I may also leave at least one unsolicited suggestion for bug prevention and code readability, the `guess` state variable is initialized as an array, is set to a string once the first row is full, and is compared against an integer near the top of the functional component. I would suggest committing to using one data type for each of your variables to prevent issues in the future. Although you *can* implicitly compare and cast types in JS, it doesn't mean you *should*.

One fun example of where comparing different data types can go wrong:

```
[] < 0 // evaluates to false

[] >= 0 // evaluates to true
```